# QTreeView Item Hover/Selected background color based on current color

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

In my project I have several `QTreeView` widgets displaying data. The background color of the items in the `QTreeView` changes depending on the data's type and association with other items.

Here is how those background colors are set:

```
QColor warning;
warning.setRgb(255, 86, 86);
model->itemFromIndex(index)->setData(warning, Qt::BackgroundRole);
```

This works, **but** I also want to have different background colors when an item is selected/hovered. I opted to use a stylesheet.

```
QTreeView::item:selected{background-color: #bedcf0;} //light blue
QTreeView::item:hover:selected{background-color: #94c8ea;} //darker blue
QTreeView::item:hover:!selected{background-color: #e6e6e6;} //gray
```

This provides the look I want, but only for items that have a white default background. If an item has a custom background color (set via `Qt::BackgroundRole`) then these hover and selected colors completely override the current background color.

What I want to happen is have every item **darken** a set amount when hovered/selected, **based on** the current background color. This is tough because `QStandardItem::setProperty()` doesn't exist.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: could you give a runnable example of the problem ?

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard Let me summarize. `QTreeView`, 20 items all with different background colors, on mouse hover, the background color should get a little darker for the hovered item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I was able to solve this myself. (pointless bounty, idk why I handed over the 50 rep before checking if it worked.)

What I did was subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and reimplement the `paint()` function.

.h

```
class MyStyledItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
      explicit MyStyledItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0){}

      virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
}
```

In this paint function I was able to check the index's UserRoles for a custom flag to decide the color I wanted. I can use `QStyle::State_Selected` and `QStyle::State_MouseOver` to check if the index is selected or hovered.Using that information, I was able to write the logic to determine the colors I wanted. After that I had to draw in the background, icon, and text manually.

.cpp

```
void MyStyledItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    //background
    QColor bgColor;
    int bgColorType(0);
    bgColorType = index.data(Qt::UserRole+9).toInt();//custom flag I set to determine which color i want

    //color logic
    if(bgColorType == 0)
        bgColor = QColor(Qt::transparent);//default is transparent to retain alternate row colors
    else if(bgColorType == 1)
        bgColor = qRgba(237, 106, 106, 255);//red
    else if(bgColorType == 2)
        bgColor = qRgba(241, 167, 226, 255);//pink
    //etc...

    QStyleOptionViewItem opt(option);

    if(option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)//check if item is selected
    {
        //more color logic
        if(bgColorType == 0)
            bgColor = qRgba(190, 220, 240, 255);
        else
            bgColor = qRgba(bgColor.red()-25, bgColor.green()-25, bgColor.blue()-25, 255);

        //background color won't show on selected items unless you do this
        opt.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Highlight, QBrush(bgColor));
    }

    if(option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)//check if item is hovered
    {
        //more color logic
        bgColor = qRgba(bgColor.red()-25, bgColor.green()-25, bgColor.blue()-25, 255);

        if(option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)//check if it is hovered AND selected
        {
            //more color logic
            if(bgColorType == 0)
            {
                bgColor = qRgba(148, 200, 234, 255);
            }

            //background color won't show on selected items unless you do this
            opt.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Highlight, QBrush(bgColor));
        }
    }


    //set the backgroundBrush to our color. This affects unselected items.
    opt.backgroundBrush = QBrush(bgColor);

    //draw the item background
    option.widget->style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelItemViewItem, &opt, painter);

    //icon
    QRect iconRect = option.rect;
    iconRect.setLeft(iconRect.left()+3);//offset it a bit to the right
    //draw in icon, this can be grabbed from Qt::DecorationRole
    //altho it appears icons must be set with setIcon()
    option.widget->style()->drawItemPixmap(painter, iconRect, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, QIcon(index.data(Qt::DecorationRole).value<QIcon>()).pixmap(16, 16));

    //text
    QRect textRect = option.rect;
    textRect.setLeft(textRect.left()+25);//offset it a bit to the right
    //draw in text, this can be grabbed from Qt::DisplayRole
    option.widget->style()->drawItemText(painter, textRect, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, option.palette, true, index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
}
```

Once that's done, I just apply the delegate to my `QTreeView` with `myTreeView->setItemDelegate(new MyStyledItemDelegate(myTreeView));`

No stylesheets, background role changes, or eventFilters required.

Comment: I have to say that in hours an researches for you and years of Qt, I have never seen QStyledItemDelegate anywhere :D I am sorry for your bounty. I give you a +1 then you lost less ^^

Comment: Lol it's no problem. I was just tired that's all. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my case cannot make it done using Qt 4.8. :(

Answer (score 1):

So I have an answer. Maybe you can tell me if it's ok for you and/or we can talk about it.

I created a custom `QTreeView` and `QStandardItem`, overwrite`mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` and set `setMouseTracking(true);` of my tree.

I got the item under the mouse with: `static_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(model())->itemFromIndex(indexAt(event->pos()))`

With that I can get with item is hovered. Then in my custom item I have a function `hovered()` and `normal()`. When the item is hovered, the method hovered is called. When the mouse move, it put the item back to normal and rehovered it if it's still on it.
The code:

HoveredTreeView.cpp:

```
#include "HoverTreeView.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

HoverTreeView::HoverTreeView(QWidget *parent)
    : QTreeView(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
}



void HoverTreeView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    while (!_hoveredItems.empty())
    {
       HoverStandardItem* oldItem = _hoveredItems.pop();
       oldItem->normal();
    }
    auto *item = static_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(model())->itemFromIndex(indexAt(event->pos()));
    HoverStandardItem* realItem = static_cast<HoverStandardItem*>(item);
    if (item) {
        realItem->hovered();
        _hoveredItems.push(realItem);
    }
}
```

HoveredTreeView.h:

```
#ifndef HOVERTREEVIEW_H
#define HOVERTREEVIEW_H

#include <QStack>
#include <QTreeView>
#include "HoverStandardItem.h"

class HoverTreeView : public QTreeView
{
public:
    HoverTreeView(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void    mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    QStack<HoverStandardItem*> _hoveredItems;
};

#endif // HOVERTREEVIEW_H
```

HoveredStandardItem.cpp:

```
#include "HoverStandardItem.h"

HoverStandardItem::HoverStandardItem(QColor const& backgroundColor, const QString &text)
    : QStandardItem(text)
    , _backgroundColor(backgroundColor)
{
    setData(backgroundColor, Qt::BackgroundColorRole);
}

void HoverStandardItem::hovered()
{
    QColor hoveredColor(_backgroundColor);
    unsigned int darker = 20;
    hoveredColor.setRgb(hoveredColor.red() - darker, hoveredColor.green() - darker, hoveredColor.blue() - darker);
    setData(hoveredColor, Qt::BackgroundColorRole);
}

void HoverStandardItem::normal()
{
    setData(_backgroundColor, Qt::BackgroundColorRole);
}
```

HoveredStandardItem.h:

```
#ifndef HOVERSTANDARDITEM_H
#define HOVERSTANDARDITEM_H

#include <QStandardItem>

class HoverStandardItem : public QStandardItem
{
public:
    HoverStandardItem(const QColor &backgroundColor, QString const& text = "");
    void hovered();
    void normal();
private:
    QColor  _backgroundColor;
};

#endif // HOVERSTANDARDITEM_H
```

I tested it in a MainWindow. Here the constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    QColor warning[3] = {
    {QColor(255, 86, 86)},
        {QColor(86, 255, 86)},
        {QColor(86, 86, 255)}
    };
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; ++j) {
        QStandardItem *parentItem = model->invisibleRootItem();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            QStandardItem *item = new HoverStandardItem(warning[j], QString("item %0 %1").arg(j).arg(i));
            parentItem->appendRow(item);
            parentItem = item;
        }
    }
    ui->treeView->setModel(model);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found several quirks with this however. First, I had to add `if(model() != nullptr)` to the `mouseMoveEvent` function to check if a model isn't set. Second, I dont specify a color upon item creation, so I removed that from the item constructor. This means the `Qt::BackgroundColorRole` is invalid by default so `setRgb` turns it black, and then can't be returned to "normal" because it defaults as invalid. Defaulting to white won't work cus I have `alternateRowColors` enabled. I opted to default it to transparent and then custom set the item background if transparent.

Comment: Third, the default "hover" effect provided by Qt is still present even though the background color is changed. How do I get rid of that default hover look? Prior to this method, I used stylesheets to set the background colors and that removed the default effect. But not anymore. Fourth, `Qt::BackgroundColorRole` is deprecated, so I switched to `Qt::BackgroundRole`.

Comment: Fifth, if the background color is changed POST item creation (which it does often for my usage), then `_backgroundColor` doesn't change to reflect the new color resulting in the color reverting to the previous color on next mouse hover event. My fix for this was to reimplement `HoverStandardItem::setData()` and update the `_backgroundColor` every time the background role is changed. I also had to add a bool to the `HoverStandardItem` class to check if `setData` was being called by the `hovered()` function, and if so, don't update `_backgroundColor`.

Comment: Basically, it's quite a mess and is way more work that I would have liked (especially since I had to change sooo many of my QStandardItem's to the new subclassed version, but it works. I'll accept this answer soon, but I still am having trouble getting the default hover effect to go away.

Comment: Okay after a ton of research and messing around, turns out that I can't edit the item's palette to remove the highlighting because I'm on Windows 7. It is using Window's default implementation and the only way I can change that is by using stylesheets. So not only is this method you showed me useless and  has multiple other problems, but the solution I need must utilize stylesheets. I wish I had my 50 rep back.